# Overflow scroll doesn't show scroll on OL tag

Tags: html, css

I created fiddle for this. Overflow scroll isn't showing scroll on ol. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/nLnum/

I assume that there is a problem with OSx Lion hiding scrolls functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It's there for me - it's just that the height is too small to display it. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/nLnum/12/

Can't you scroll that?

If you wan't more vertical space, use overflow-y instead, to remove the blank scroll bar: http://jsfiddle.net/nLnum/11/

Comment: I can scroll it but I cant see it. I am on Mac Lion

Comment: I had to increase the height of the `ol` to 50px (and add a couple more `li`s before FF would show arrows/scrolling. The children of the container have height attributes -- if those don't push open their parent's height far enough....no scroll bars needed. The UI also needs X amount of vertical space to show the buttons, scroll position, etc. Your original code has a max-height of 20px. I'm guessing the UI needs around 50px to show it's buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I updated you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLnum/9/). You were setting max height of ol as 20px

Comment: I am using Mac OS Lion and Chrome and scroll is not visible